# Do I delete my question?

Tags: discussion, bad-questions

My question [Does copying all cookie *.txt files from XP to Win7 work?](https://superuser.com/questions/719083/does-copying-all-cookie-txt-files-from-xp-to-win7-work) is based on the mis-assumption that the .txt cookie files must have been generated by FireFox (see body text).

Thanks to the commenters that became clear.

Now what do I do - delete this question because it was based on an incorrect assumption, or leave it because there may still be value in the thread. I can imagine others may have the same confusion.

Maybe add an answer?

Answer (score 5):

There's no reason to delete, add in a self answer mentioning your findings

Comment: Just to clarify, use the Answer box, don't edit your original questions.